# How can I find out which USB device (if any) is being disabled for using too much power?

Tags: usb, power

As I use my Macbook, which is connected to a large number of USB hubs and devices, every few minutes I get a notification saying "USB Accessories Disabled; Unplug the accessory using too much power to re-enable USB devices." However, as far as I can tell, none of my USB devices ever stop working, and I don't have to unplug anything to continue using them. And yet the notification pops up again after another few minutes. I would like to figure out which USB device or combination of devices is causing this notification, or else determine if the notification is spurious and not caused by any device. For example, can I find out in the logs somewhere which device triggered the notification?

I know I can theoretically solve this by unplugging all the devices one by one, but this is not a desirable solution because the notification does not *always* appear reliably every few minutes, so after unplugging a device it is difficult to determine if the notification has stopped appearing or if it has simply not reappeared *yet*. So, debugging the problem in this way would take many hours or perhaps days, hence my desire for a more direct solution.

Note that the vast majority of my USB devices are connected to hubs that have separate power supplies, so they should not be drawing power from the Macbook itself, and in any case they are mostly low-power devices like a keyboard, mouse, microphone, webcam, etc.

Comment: You’ll get this info from the console (as it happens), but the enumeration of the hubs/ports are octets (hex values) and not “human readable”. In other words, you won’t see anything that says “FooBar USB3 Hub Port 3“. That said, having a port disabled for too much power draw on a powered USB hub is concerning.

Comment: @Allan I don't know for sure that the offending device is on one of the powered hubs. Is there any way to convert the hex values to something human readable?

Comment: Start with the command `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` to get all the devices connected to USB.  Then, you’d have to x-ref these devices with what get’s output on the console.  As for doing this realtime, you’ll need a helper app (I don’t know of any) to do the translation for you.